# Network Adapter Driver keeps failing

Tags: windows-10, drivers, network-adapter

I have a HP laptop. For the past three days, every 2 to 4 hours, i get kicked out of my wifi and when I try to connect, It says "[**Can't connect to this Network**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRf1K.jpg)". When I run the network troubleshooter, I get a message saying "[**The Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bgn Wi-Fi Adapter adapter is experiencing driver- or hardware-related problems.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rPBe.png)". Then [the wifi button disappears completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rstte.png). And a [warning symbol appears on the driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21zGZ.png) in the Device Manager. After I restart, It works for another 2 to 4 hours then rinse and repeat.

**P.S.** All the Images are attached to their respective text above.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

-Updating the driver(It says the driver is up-to-date)
-Uninstalling the driver(After restarting, works for 2 to 4 hours then fails)
-Installing the latest driver from HP for my laptop model (You can guess that nothing happens)
-Check for windows updates (There was an update but it was a windows defender update and nothing was fixed even after updating)
-Rolling back the driver to the previous version(My laptop is pretty old so there was no driver update for 5 years or so but I tried it anyways)

If you have anything I can do to fix this problem, Please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the HP Recovery Manager installed? https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04762483

Comment: Try a USB Network Adapter and see if that works.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like a hardware problem, since it sounds like the device itself is causing a kernel error or perhaps crashing. Windows doesn’t really handle certain hardware device errors well.